# How to get rid of the warning when adding a class to the class map While the value in the map is inherited from another class?

Tags: java

I'm trying to add a value to the map. This value is inherited from the class DecryptManager.class at the same time, if the class is not inherited from DecryptManager, I want to issue a WARN
How can this be done?

```
static Map<String, Class<? extends DecryptManager>> decryptManagers = new HashMap<>();

    private static void registerDecryptManager(Map<String, Class<?>> decryptManagerClass,MessageDecryptor ano) {
            decryptManagers.put(ano.participantTitle(), decryptManagerClass);
        }
```

[image]

```
public interface DecryptManager {

        String decrypt(long id) throws SuspendExecution;

    }
```

Comment: Does `MessageDecryptor` extend or implement `DecryptManager`?

Comment: `public interface DecryptManager {

        String decrypt(long id) throws SuspendExecution;

    }`

Comment: That does not answer the question...

Comment: implement DecryptManager

Comment: What do you mean by "I want to issue a WARN"?  Do you mean you want to write a WARN entry to the log?

Comment: Yes and issue an exception

Comment: If it were me I would set the Generics on the `Map` to only accept `DecryptManager` then you would get a compile time error, much cheaper to fix.  However if that is not possible for whatever reason you will have to check if the `decryptManagerClass` is an instance of `DecryptManager` if its not, use your logging frameworks log methods to log a warn and then throw and appropriate exception.